# Gas range has the wrong burner try to ignite

Tags: gas, stove, range

When I try to light the front right burner, on my Amana first edition range, the front left burner sparks.  The gas turns on to the correct burner but it try to spark the wrong burner.  This problem just popped up out of no where after years of the range working correctly.  I would appreciate any help or advice anyone can share.

Comment: Some ranges spark *all* of the burners at the same time, so the "wrong burner" sparking may be a red herring. Can you light the problem burner with a match? If so, it could be an issue with the spark on that burner. If not, probably a gas supply issue. Either way, try removing the burner cap and lifting off the burner to see if it is mis-aligned or if some food got stuck in there.

Comment: Follow Henry Jackson comment.  But it is not just food you need to inspect for.  Over time the igniters develop corrosion that needs to be scraped off.  With a small piece of fine grain sand paper (200 or higher) or a small fine file, lightly (I mean lightly) clean the probe and the side of the burner where it sparks.

Comment: and the igniters need to be gapped with the correct gap, que no?

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, **most** spark ignition ranges spark **all** the burners at the same time.

So, it's probably just an issue with that burner not sparking - spark gap shorted out with food is the usual cause. Broken wire is possible but much less likely.

Try looking at the left front burner spark (which you see when trying to light the front right) while lighting each of the back burners. I'll bet it sparks for both of them, too; and I'll also bet the back burners will spark while you are lighting the front ones - you probably just haven't looked for that before.

Comment: I've had to clean the burner side of the contact with a wire brush to get it to spark again.  You could measure the resistance between igniters to determine if the wire is broken.

Comment: "In my experience, most spark ignition ranges spark all the burners at the same time." What?! I have never seen this! And I've seen many different ranges - Wolf, Viking, DCS, Capital, BlueStar.

Answer (score 1):

My burner would not start and when I manually lit it the flame was very yellow like the air mixture was off. I found the problem was some of the fiberglass insulation that Frigidaire put under the burner base between the top of the oven moved and was blocking the air flow to the burner. To see this insulation remove the cap and burner and look inside the hole and see if some of the fiberglass insulation has moved into the airway where the air comes to mix with the gas. By pushing the fiberglass with a chopstick back away from the air path and back into the area between the burner and the oven it fixed the problem. Easy fix if you know what to look for.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on a GE JGP933SEF1SS 4-burner drop in gas stove from 2003.  The back left burner stopped working after someone in the house, not mentioning any names, cleaned the stove with a wet sponge.  This person had done this before where all the burners were sparking when not in use, so figured this was the same issue.  After replacing the ignitor box and the wiring harness (the one under the switches) the problem was not fixed.  This means either the ignitor wire or the ignitor itself.  I tried the sand paper/brush deal to clean the spark point.  No success.  So, I wanted to find out if it was the ignitor or the wire to the ignitor, so I swapped the ignitor from the back left burner with the front left burner, and when I went to test it, they both worked.  I don't know how or why it worked just by swapping them (perhaps some loose wire, perhaps some debris in the wire connector, I don't know).  Swapping them though would at least have confirmed, for me, if it were the ignitor or the wire.  Hope that helps someone.